# How to feed ranked multiple labels for a single image to a supervised training pipeline

Tags: image, pytorch, classification, supervised-learning

In supervised learning for image classification, we feed the training images with its labels. **Is it possible for each image, can I provide a series of label ranked in the order of relatedness instead of just one label?**

I am using PyTorch for this supervised training. Right now, under each label, I have my training images for that label. Can anyone plz help me saying how can I implement ranked multi-label image training in PyTorch?

Answer (score 0):

A more concrete example would help understand your issue better. But from what I understand you are not tackling a classic classification problem where we would use CrossEntropyLoss, but you want to learn a measure of relatedness.

The best method I know for such is using metric learning (learning to rank is an example that seems to fit your problem). Triplet Learning is particularly famous, but there are other methods that make it possible. You may want to take a look here: https://gombru.github.io/2019/04/03/ranking_loss/, and here: https://towardsdatascience.com/image-similarity-using-triplet-loss-3744c0f67973

In short metric learning maps the input to a feature vector. The training is done such that similar inputs are mapped to a neighborhood of the feature space and dissimilar examples are mapped to distant parts of the feature space.

Minimal (PyTorch based) code for that:

```
# bare bone initialization
loss_func = nn.TripletMarginLoss(swap=True)
feature_extractor = Model(feat_size=1024)
optim = Adam(feature_extractor.parameters())

for x, x_pos, x_neg in dataloader:
    # x contains the data we want to correctly rank;
    # x_pos contains examples that should be mapped close to x;
    # x_neg contains examples that should be mapped far from x;
    optim.zero_grad()

    # extract features of each input        
    feat_x = feature_extractor(x)
    feat_x_pos = feature_extractor(x_pos)
    feat_x_neg = feature_extractor(x_neg)

    # calculate the loss based on those inputs
    loss = loss_func(feat_x, feat_x_pos, feat_x_neg)

    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
```

PyTorch makes a lot of stuff really simple to implement! The tricky part is designing a training pipeline that fits your needs.